Power apps - Send email with attachment error
Good morning, everyone!
I am beginner and i am making a power app to send email with multi attachment.
I have 5 attachment controls.
It is work for send email with 1 attachment control, below is my code
Office365Outlook.SendEmailV2(
"alan@c.com.hk",
"Subject",
"Body",
{
    Attachments: ForAll(
        Attachment_Inspection_Record.Attachments,
        {
            ContentBytes: Value,
            Name: Name
        }
    )
})

But it is causing error if send email with 5 attachment control attachment, below is my code:
Office365Outlook.SendEmailV2(
"alan@c.com.hk",
"Subject",
"Body",
{
    Attachments: ForAll(
        Attachment_Inspection_Record.Attachments,
        {
            ContentBytes: Value,
            Name: Name
        },
        Attachment_CCM.Attachments,
        {
            ContentBytes: Value,
            Name: Name
        },
         Attachment_Sitephoto_1.Attachments,
        {
            ContentBytes: Value,
            Name: Name
        }
        Attachment_Sitephoto_2.Attachments,
        {
            ContentBytes: Value,
            Name: Name
        }
        Attachment_Sitephoto_3.Attachments,
        {
            ContentBytes: Value,
            Name: Name
        }
    )

    
});

Would anyone can help?
Thank you very much.

The ForAll function can be used to transform a table into another - but what you are trying to do is to combine (union) multiple tables, which is not what it does. You can use the Table function to do that - either combining all the attachment controls at first, then using ForAll to extract the name/content, or combining the extracted values that you have working for one control.
For example, the first option would be similar to the expression below:
Office365Outlook.SendEmailV2(
    "alan@c.com.hk",
    "Subject",
    "Body",
    {
        Attachments: ForAll(
            Table(
                Attachment_Inspection_Record.Attachments,
                Attachment_CCM.Attachments,
                Attachment_Sitephoto_1.Attachments,
                Attachment_Sitephoto_2.Attachments,
                Attachment_Sitephoto_3.Attachments
            ),
            {
                ContentBytes: Value,
                Name: Name
            }
        )
    }
);

While the second would be similar to this:
Office365Outlook.SendEmailV2(
    "alan@c.com.hk",
    "Subject",
    "Body",
    {
        Attachments: Table(
            ForAll(
                Attachment_Inspection_Record.Attachments,
                {
                    ContentBytes: Value,
                    Name: Name
                }
            ),
            ForAll(
                Attachment_CCM.Attachments,
                {
                    ContentBytes: Value,
                    Name: Name
                }
            ),
            ForAll(
                Attachment_Sitephoto_1.Attachments,
                {
                    ContentBytes: Value,
                    Name: Name
                }
            ),
            ForAll(
                Attachment_Sitephoto_2.Attachments,
                {
                    ContentBytes: Value,
                    Name: Name
                }
            ),
            ForAll(
                Attachment_Sitephoto_3.Attachments,
                {
                    ContentBytes: Value,
                    Name: Name
                }
            )
        )
    }
);

Both should work fine.

It works, thank you very much for your help
